# How i get mysql json via nodejs return

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, bots, discord

Details: Below I have 2 projects (API and BOT Discord).
I can get data from my MySQL and show it on the web. but I can not do show in json, without first going through an arrays.

I need to return it in json so I can get data from BOT (also in nodejs.)

So, i want remove the **[ ]** keys for work perfect my project.

criminals.js -> Discord BOT

```
const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/criminals/49');
   console.log(res.data.id);
```

Already try change **res.data.id** but no result changes.

CriminalsControll.js -> API

```
async show(req, res) {
        // Show unique details

        var results = db.query(`SELECT * from lspd WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`, function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;

            //make results 
            var resultJson = JSON.stringify(results);
            resultJson = JSON.parse(resultJson);
            var apiResult = {};

            //add our JSON results to the data table
            apiResult.data = resultJson;

            return res.json(resultJson);
        });

    },
```

WEB Return ->

```
[
  {
    "id": 49,
    "nom": "Filipe",
    "telephone": "232323",
    "steam": "12345678",
    "crime": "Roubo de veiculo / Tentativa de fuga / Tentativa de Homicidio a Policial.",
    "sanction": "Pegou 1000 de multa por Furto de veiculo. Foi preso por 5 Anos por Roubo de veiculo + 5 anos de tentativa de Fuga",
    "user_id": 5,
    "DateHour": "2019-11-16T21:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

Thx for any help :}

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a javascript array, hence the `[]` around your object. In order to access the first object, you'll have to use one of the following approaches:

**Assume the following variable is your API response:**

```
const array = [{ id: 1 }]
```

**Accessing by the first array key:**

```
let criminal = array[0]

console.log(criminal) // {id: 1}
console.log(criminal.id) // 1
```

**Or using array destructuring (only available in ES6):**

```
let [first] = array

console.log(first) // {id: 1}
console.log(first.id) // 1
```

**Or using lodash/underscore:**

```
let criminal = _.first(array)

console.log(criminal) // {id: 1}
console.log(criminal.id) // 1
```

**If you want to return only the object from your API (nodejs)**

```
// async show ()
let [criminal] = resultJson
return res.json(criminal);
```